# Trying to compute misclassifiction error for bagging classifier in R, getting error message

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm trying to compute the misclassification error on my data for the bagging classifier. I've done it successfully for two other sets of data by doing it this way:

```
mydata.bagging <- bagging(V5~., data=mydata, mfinal=10)
mydata.bagging.pred <- predict.bagging(mydata.bagging,newdata=mydata)
mydata.bagging.pred$confusion
mydata.bagging.pred$error
```

And it's worked perfectly fine. However, when I try to do the same thing with my third data, I get an error message that says

```
#Error in cbind(yval2, yprob, nodeprob) : number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I'm assuming this is because the third data has fewer rows than the other 2, but how would I be able to fix this problem and find the misclassification error?

Comment: Probably NA's someplace but where is anybody's guess. If you cannot post an example then, at a very minumum, post a better description of the data!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and then figured it out.

It is possible that all of your left-hand side values (V5) are the same. The error is thrown as a saying that no decision can be made as it is too easy.

My source: http://kleinfelter.com/learning-r-painful-r-learnings

Comment: Please add a minimal explanation in the answer itself, as the link provided may happen to unavailable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After removing all 'NA', the problem has gone. Also, the first column has to be index column.